# Скачать 12 000 изображений по url

Tags: php, url

У меня есть 12 000 ссылок на картинки.

Пример: `https://img.rl0.ru/afisha/e920x1380q85i/s1.afisha.ru/mediastorage/e2/f7/299c8320690c451485bc8966f7e2.jpg`

Как с помощью php или другим способом скачать все картинки к себе на компьютер?

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: Вы можете скачать одну картинку?

Comment: Естественно могу

Comment: Тогда в чём сложность скачать 12000? Просто проитерируйте список. Но обязательно делайте задержку между запросами. Если сервис явно не указывает допустимое количество запросов, то я бы не слал больше 1 в секунду